# JavaMail Fails to deliver mail due to getting only hostName rather than FQDN from one server

Tags: dns, jakarta-mail, fqdn

JavaMail  Fails to deliver mail - For x.y.z.com it retuns only x (hostname) with use of 
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

For Test server , it returns FQDN with getHostName() but for Prod Server , only returns hostname.

It seems like it's not able to resolve DNS entry in the Prod Server.

Changing configuraion in /etc/hosts - breaks other non java mails which depend on mailx program.

These are Unix based servers.

Test Server - Java Version - 1.6.0.31
Prod Server - Java Version - 1.6.0.25

Could that be due to difference in version , InetAddress not able to resolve to FQDN??

Answer (score 0):

More likely it's due to a difference in the way the name service is setup on the two machines.  You can set the System property mail.smtp.localhost as a workaround.